# Rake db:migrate and db:create not operated with proper database files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, rake

I know this question has come up on stackoverflow before, and I have tried the various solutions suggested, even trying to restart my current app. But none of them worked. I am trying to change my database to postgres. Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  aadapter: postgresql
  database: development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'



gem 'pg'


# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
```

I have removed approriate dependicies in my Gemfile.lock and changes RAILS_ENV variable. No luck any time. Here is my trace:

```
   rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:52:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:175:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:173:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/fuzzyliz/rails_projects/roommaker/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/fuzzyliz/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you may be getting an issue because of a typo in your development definition.

Also as a suggestion I would try to define a little more in your database.yml. I am not sure encoding is needed or what the minimal options are but here is what a typical definition looks like for my PG projects

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
```